# Nativescript Views/Pages

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Is it possible to have native script pages to be grouped into folders ?

I tried to create a folder called views, and a sub folder called intro and within it I had my pages. When I ran the app it stated that it could not find the page.

When I moved the pages back into the app folder everything worked.

Comment: Example of nested folders inside NativeScript = Angular  app https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/tree/master/app/pages/apod/toolbar

Comment: Example of nested folders inside NativeScript Core app https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Cosmos-Databank/tree/master/app/views/apod

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'm actually using your firebaseAuth as the start for my project. I think what I'm running into is possibly in this issue : https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-webpack/issues/6 it's suggesting that each page etc... needs to be registered.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but without seeing some code hard to tell why you are running into such issues. May be you may try to reproduce the issue with playground and share the same.